# How to run a JSON after other JSON is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

I am using the same solution as this question. However, I want to load another JSON file after the `when()` method. So in `when()` I get a JSON data, then based on that, inside the `then()` method, I want to load another JSON.

Here is my code:

```
var myJSON;
var myJSON2;

function _parseJSON() {
  // return here, no need returning exactly what you would expect anyhow
  return $.getJSON(settings.json_src);
}

function _parseJSON2(term) {
  return $.getJSON("http://website.com/" + term ".json");
}

// because you returned, you can chain everything nicely together
$.when( _parseJSON() )
  // don't forget the argument here
  .then(function( data ) { 
        myJSON = data; 
        myJSON2 = _parseJSON2(data.value);
   })
  // and these will only run after the myJSON got set
  .then( _cacheOptions )
  .then( _cacheDom )
  .then( _events )
  .then( _render );
```

The line `myJSON2 = _parseJSON2(data.value);` has to be ran when `data` is loaded and `myJSON2` must be saved as a variable to be used later in the code. 
It is more like another `when().then()` is required.

Any idea how to make this working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.when` is actually redundant but that isn't causing issues really

What you are missing with the `_parseJSON2(data.value)` is to return it as a promise and simultaneously assign it's *response* to `myJSON2`

You could do something like:

```
function _parseJSON() {      
  return $.getJSON(settings.json_src)               
}
/**
* Receives data from _parseJSON() and asssigns to myJSON variable
* Assigns new response to myJSON2
*/
function _parseJSON2(data) {
  myJSON = data;
  const term = myJSON.value
  return $.getJSON("http://website.com/" + term ".json")
            // this is the then() you were missing
            .then(function(data){
                myJSON2 = data;
                // optionally return myJSON2 to next `then()`
             });
}

// $.when not really needed
_parseJSON()
  .then( _parseJSON2 ) 
  .then( _cacheOptions )
  .then( _cacheDom )
  .then( _events )
  .then( _render );
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just one question. `_parseJSON2` takes and arg, but I see you called it without that. Is that possible? if not, what value will it get?

Comment: It does get it because instead of using an anonymous function in `then` it gets the argument that anonymous function gets. Do a log of `data` where `myJSON= data` is assigned...will see it there

Answer (score -1):

According to mozila.org

No need to use jQuery if you use fetch function

```
fetch("http://website.com/" + term ".json")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
});
```